# Format four decimal places in C#

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, data-structures, logic

I have this algorithm and I need to format it to 4 decimal places after the decimal point, how can I do this algorithm that I have?

**Given that an input is: 2.00, then my output must be 12.5664**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double n = 3.14159;
            double raio = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            double area = n * Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(raio), 2);

            Console.WriteLine($"A={area}");
        }
```

Comment: [Give the docs a look](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: .ToString("N4")

Comment: You need to say what didn't work.

Comment: This scenario works, just add also

`double raio = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass it as format string with the amount of decimal places you want:

```
        double n = 3.14159;
        double raio = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        
        //fixed converting a double from a variable that was already a double
        double area = n * Math.Pow(raio, 2);

        Console.WriteLine($"A={area.ToString("#.####")}");

        //if you need to get the rounded number to do another calculation with
        double roundedArea = Double.Parse(area.ToString("#.####"));
```

Comment: I tested with this approach, but this is a code smell, I tried it with ToString ("F4") and the answer was better accepted

Comment: @Dolla There is no smell, it is a standard formatting capability. "better accepted" by what?

Comment: I'm on an online code site and when sending the code the answer was "wrong answer", for some reason ToString("F4") the answer was "accepted"

Comment: `Convert.ToDouble(something-that-is-already-a-double)` is an *actual* code smell, and much worse at that imo

Answer (score 2):

double area =123.4567;

// max. two decimal places

String.Format("{0:0.####}", area);      // "123.4567"

String.Format("{0:0.##}", area);         // "123.46"

String.Format("{0:0}", area);         // "123"

Comment: <p>Consider Last one should be String.Format("{0:0}", area); // "123"</p>